# Multiple InfluxDB columns in Grafana table

Tags: python, grafana, influxdb, flux

Currently struggling with the easiest task. I want to display a table with log entries in Grafana based on InfluxDB entries. The current implementation looks like the following picture

[image]

This results from an simple

```
from(bucket:"name") 
|> range(start: -10m)
```

Flux query while my entries are written as

```
p = Point("title_meas").field("column_data", value_data).time(timestamp)).tag(tag_key, tag_value)
```

The only thing I want to achieve is a table with multiple columns (so I tried adding a tag to my data as a workaround for a third column) resulting in an table like:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I felt really lost cause of the lack of examples facing the new InfluxDb2.0 - Grafana - Flux Query relationship. This [Example Dashboard](https://play.grafana.org/d/OhR1ID6Mk/3-table?orgId=1) helped me a lot figuring out whats going on in case anyone else struggles with this kind of basic cluelessness.

Comment: You can use influx pivot function to convert your values into individual rows:
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/flux/stdlib/built-in/transformations/pivot/